# unable to upload the php password field into phpmyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, phpmyadmin

I have an HTML form which accepts the first name, last name, username, and password of the user and I am uploading the values to my local **phpMyAdmin** but I am unable to upload the password field into the database.

This is my HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="first" required placeholder="John*">
<input type="text" name="last" required placeholder="Doe*">
<input type="text" name="username" id="vname" placeholder="jondoe11*" />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="vpassword" placeholder="*****" />
```

and my php file

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "credentials";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {      
    die("Connection failed: ");  
}  else
{    echo "connnected";  }

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];


$sql =$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password, first, last) values(?,?,?,?)');
$sql->bind_param('ssss', $user,$password,$first,$last);
$val = $sql->execute();
?>
```

I can successfully enter all the values except for the password field.
Please help

Comment: Sometimes your data type of password field in mysql might not match the data type of your passing value. This happened for me when I kept a integer field for phone number and passed a string value. Make sure your data types are matching each other

Comment: Hi could you also give info about your password field database type please . Or a SQL of your database to see the stucture of the base.

Comment: Just use $user_password instead of $password . Updated code : `$sql->bind_param('ssss', $user,$user_password ,$first,$last);`

Comment: The data type in the form and in the database is matching. The data type of password field in my database is longtext.

Comment: @AshokGujjar Thanks. I changed $password to $user_password and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @TenzinTridhe, just flag my comment as useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having variable `$password` for your database connection and also accessing the same variable for datapass. I changed the data variable to `$user_password`. Hope this will work for you.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "credentials";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {      
    die("Connection failed: ");  
}  else
{    echo "connnected";  }

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$user_password = $_POST['pass'];


$sql =$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password, first, last) values(?,?,?,?)');
$sql->bind_param('ssss', $user,$user_password,$first,$last);
$val = $sql->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But I didn't understand the logic behind it. Why is $password not working and $user_password is working? Is $password a keyword?

Comment: You have initialized `$password ` variable for your data connection which is passed to the function/constructor  `mysqli()` . It's a bad practice to reuse the db connection variable. I am not sure why your code wasn't working. But I recommend you to not to use the variable `$password ` since it's a part of db connection. If you found this answer is helpful upvote and tick it correct. Thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use constant define() for connecting Database, not use a variable. like this define('SERVER', 'localhost'); and so on.